# Publishing results posted Stack Exchange

Tags: publications

Recently, I asked a question on stack exchange, to check if something I am working on was already done. I myself could not find this specific thing, so I asked the community.

Then, a discussion about my problem followed, and some people provided (possibly inaccurate) proofs. Independently, I figured out a proof by myself.

Now, I want to publish the proof of my result. Is this ok? Can I post this on Stack Exchange and then still publish it?